# installing SQL Server 2008 on virtual machine connected to a domain windows server 2003

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, database-connection

i have a visual machine running windows xp, I installed SQL Server 2008 Enterprise evaluation (free), during the installation process it ask me to put SQL database users something like SQL agent ... it didn't accept any user  except **MyDomain/Administrator and its Password** when the install finished and open the SQL Management studio click on the cross beside the databases folder and the error is *Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)*

any help would be great

the full error msg :

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
------------------------------

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ESCAPE'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 156)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=10.00.1442&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=156&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is an authentication issue.  Looks more like a broken installation, my best guess is that management studio is issuing a command that the database engine isn't recognising.

Was this a completely clean install? If not I would rebuild the VM, do a full Windows update and then re-install.

If you don't want to re-install you could try installing just Management Studio on your development machine and then connect in to the VM with Mgmt Studio running locally.